# Command Block not working perfectly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using a Command Block and I'm trying to put a very small redstone pulse in the the redstone circuit.

The my idea is to use a powered redstone wire but the my command is not working.

I'm using this command:

```
/setblock x y z redstone_wire 15
```

But the command block place a normal redstone wire.

Can you tell me how I can put a powered redstone wire (with the full power).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redstone is not powered by anything, and is soon ticked, so the pulse dissipates before it is able to do anything. I suggest placing a redstone block and then quickly replacing it with unpowered wire.